# I Want To Copy Files with set /p On Batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a file with `set /p`. Task: Write a file name with set /p and that will be copied in a directory that I want, but it doesn't work.

My current source:

```
@echo off
echo Enter YOur Pic Name With .jpg
set /p cop=
xcopy /s %systemroot%\%cop% %systemroot%\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds
cls
pause
```

Comment: Please specify "is doesn't work".

Comment: I suggest you to edit the topic description by another more precise one. Note that the file is _not_ copied with `set /p` command, but with `xcopy` instead. This detail is important because there _is_ a way to copy a file using `set /p` command!

Comment: do you have write access to `%systemroot%`?

Comment: What I Should To do ? @Stephan

Answer (score 0):

For the `SET /P` command, the format works best like this:

```
set /p cop=Enter your Pic name with .jpg
```

I'd also suggest you add a couple of lines to check if the file is actually there:

```
@rem just check that the full path is what I expect
echo %systemroot%\%cop%
@rem and check if the file is there
dir %systemroot%\%cop%
```

(Delete these lines once your batch file is working).

Also, delete the `cls` line, until it's working.  Then, once it's doing what you need, you can put it back in, if you want.

You might want to think about whether `%systemroot%` is the right place for these pictures, even temporarily. It's usually used for Windows OS code.

Comment: Ty For A Answer My File Is there and Its Doesn't Matter That My File In %systemroot% Cause I Just Want To Copy Into Oobe Folder To Change Win7 Login Pic But It Doesn't Copy

Comment: Tnx For Answer But I Dont Understand Im Sure That My file is there but That Not Copy On The Oobe Folder

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that %systemroot% path may have spaces, so file names must be enclosed in quotes:

```
@echo off
set /p "cop=Enter YOur Pic Name With .jpg: "
xcopy /s "%systemroot%\%cop%" "%systemroot%\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds"
cls
pause
```

Comment: If "Not Work" I am pretty sure that an error message is displayed on the screen... What is it?

Answer (score 0):

try running as admin: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token

also you may try the following (xcopy doesn't like the `/s`), I think you're trying to silence the output, just try with the `>nul` redirect:

```
@echo off
echo Enter YOur Pic Name With .jpg
set /p cop=
xcopy /y %systemroot%\%cop% %systemroot%\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds\* >nul
cls
pause
```